# trying to extract data from txt file into and html

Tags: html, css

guys I'm doing a project game, and I'm having a struggle when I try to extract a text file content into an HTML I made.

currently, the game creates a score.txt file with the player score, and I'm trying to make an HTML that will show this score in the HTML automatically.

I will add my current HTML for reference so you could check it out:

This is the part of the code I'm struggling with

```
<h1><div id ="score">The score is <?p$ filename = 
fopen('score.txt', 'r');
$file = fread($filename, filesize('score.txt'));
echo $file;
fclose($filename); </div> </h1>
<hr class="w3-border-grey" style="margin:auto;width:40%">
<p class="w3-large w3-center">Good job traveler!</p>
</div>
<div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-padding-large">
```

Comment: Please post the code as text not an image.

Comment: Also, this does not seem to be Python?

Answer (score 0):

`<?php $myfile = fopen("webdictionary.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!"); echo fread($myfile,filesize("webdictionary.txt")); fclose($myfile); ?>`

- This should solve it
- If in any case it doesn't work please refer to this url https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp

Comment: It didn’t work unfortunately do I need to put the text file in the same directory maybe?

Comment: Just give the path of the file Like this

fopen("D:\xampp\htdocs\google-ads-php\examples\Reporting\webdictionary.txt", "r")

or put the file in same directory